# why Anaconda does not recommend to set path environment variable

Tags: python, anaconda

`Anaconda3 5.3.0 64bit`.

During installation process, I check the option to add Anaconda in my PATH environment variable. Then it does not recommend me to do that. It says:

> Instead, open Anaconda with the Windows Start menu and select "Anaconda (64-bit)". This "add to PATH" option makes Anaconda get found before previously installed software, but may cause problems requiring you to install and reinstall Anaconda.

What does it really mean? I would like to add it to PATH because I would like to work also by means of the command line interface, but I would not like to have problems.

Comment: It's Anaconda trying to cover their asses, basically, because users tend to do weird things that can lead to issues. For example, imagine if someone installed Anaconda twice (in two separate locations). Maybe they forgot they already installed Anaconda, so they install it again. On the first install, if they chose to add that install of Anaconda to the PATH variable, then the PATH is already set for that first install. Now when the user installs it a second time, the user is EXPECTING the path to go to the second install location, but it would still go to the first. This is problematic!

Comment: Weird! Then, can I check to add it to PATH without problems? Of course I will never install it a second time :D I would like that, when I code, I can use the prompt and the comman "python" to compile and execute my code..

Comment: I can't 100% guarantee you'll never encounter problems, but I will say that I have anaconda installed, have anaconda added to my PATH variable, and I've never encountered any problems despite using it frequently. I added both \anaconda3\ and \anaconda3\Scripts\ to the path.

Comment: That's great.. I will report any problems that should arise. Thank you! :)

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero Your comment should be an answer. I'd upvote it!

Answer (score 2):

If Python is already installed and is being used by other programs, setting the conda path again can lead to unwanted conflicts.

For this reason Anaconda provides a separate cmd line/Powershell interface called Anaconda prompt which sets the PATH as long as the shell is open.

If you're installing Python for the first time using Anaconda, there shouldn't be any problems.

You can create environments using conda if you want to  work with different python versions. Anaconda will automatically set the path for both scenarios once the environment is activated.